# C++ Declaration and instantiation of scoped variable with curly braces instead of assignment operator

Tags: c++, c++11, scope

I am watching Bjarne Stroustrup's Keynote on C++11 Style ([link](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style)) (00:35:30) and am having troubles understanding the following (code copied from the slide):

```
void f(int n, int x)
{
      Gadget g {n};
      // ...
      if (x<100) throw std::run_time_error{"Weird!"};
      if (x<200) return;
      // ...
}
```

I tried compiling this code using a struct as well as an object but in both cases the compiler tells me that it is  expecting a ';' at the end of the declaration of `Gadget g` and won't compile.

My questions therefore are:

- Am I correct to assume that `g` is being instantiated?
- What type of object must `Gadget` be for this code to compile?
- What concept is at work on this line: `Gadget g {n};`? i.e. What are the curly braces after the declaration?
- (probably too broad, but) Why would the compiler not recognize the curly braces as valid syntax?

Comment: That is c++11 syntax. You need the relevant compiler support.

Comment: Just use a C++11 compliant compiler, and use the `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x` flag

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Am I correct to assume that g is being instantiated?

Yes, you are correct.

> What type of object must `Gadget` be for this code to compile?

Any type that can be initialized from an `int`. For instance, if your `Gadget` class has a constructor taking an `int`, or taking something that can be initialized directly from an `int`, that makes the code compile.

> What concept is at work on this line: `Gadget g {n};`? i.e. What are the curly braces after the declaration?

That's uniform initialization syntax. It eliminates some nasty problem with the parentheses notation that would make the C++ compiler parse the following as a function declaration (rather than as the initialization of an object):

```
struct Widget { /* ... */ };
struct Gadget { Gadget(Widget const&) { /* ... */ } /* ... */ };

Gadget g(Widget()); // This is parsed a FUNCTION DECLARATION
```

In the above example, the intent of the programmer may have been to construct an object `g` of type `Gadget` and initialize it from a temporary `Widget` object: however, the compiler would parse this as the declaration of a function called `g` that returns a `Gadget` and takes as its argument a (pointer to a) function that accepts no arguments and returns a `Widget`. This is known as the [**Most Vexing Parse**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) problem.

Notice, that when using braces the above problem does not exist:

```
Gadget g{Widget{}}; // This could not be possibly parsed as a function declaration!
```

> (probably too broad, but) Why would the compiler not recognize the curly braces as valid syntax?

That's most likely because you are not using a C++11-compliant compiler. You should be using one, and use the `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x` compilation flag to enable C++11 support.

Comment: `using Gadget = int;` would probably be the simples type that can be initialised from an int ;)